# Caching ManyToMany "self" relationships in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model with self-referencing ManyToMany field:

```
class Suite(models.Model):
    suites = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="parents",
                                            summetrical=False
                                   )
```

Current usage of displaying a list of suites is fetching a list of "master_suites" (suites that have zero parents) and starting from those recursively doing "suite.subsuites.all()" until all are exhausted.

The current way is generating a database query for each such suite, and I would like to add caching to it.

The whole process could be done with loading a list of suites first, Suite.objects.all(); and a list of subsuites: Suite.subsuites.through.all() and using these two datasets to construct the tree.

I want to add this "logic" to the ManyRelatedManager, cache the Suite.subsuites.through.all() results, and use the cache during the loops in the views.

But I found no way to set a custom ManyRelatedManager of my own ... how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking at a wrong direction. You might want to use [custom manager](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) for this case, to construct your query set, cache it and so anything else you desire.

Usage, could look like this:

```
suite_tree = Suite.mymanager.construct_tree();
```